# How do I refactor a ReadLine loop to Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to make below code cleaner (in the eye of the beholder).

```
var lines = new StringReader(lotsOfIncomingLinesWithNewLineCharacters);
var resultingLines = new List<string>();

string line;
while( (line = lines.ReadLine() ) != null )
{
    if( line.Substring(0,5) == "value" )
    {
        resultingLines.Add(line);
    }
}
```

to something like

```
var resultingLinesQuery = 
    lotsOfIncomingLinesWithNewLineCharacters
    .Where(s=>s.Substring(0,5) == "value );
```

Hopefully I have illustrated that I'd *prefer* to not have the result as a list (to not fill up memory) and that StringReader is not mandatory.

There is the naïve solution to create an extension and move the ReadLine there but I have a feeling there might be a better way.

Comment: As a general guideline, avoid turning something that has side effects into an `IEnumerable<T>` (such as reading from a stream, which changes the stream's state). Enumerating such sequences repeatedly might yield different results every time. This easily leads to unexpected query results. This is the reason why LINQ does not have a `.ForEach` operator: Such an operator would be a direct replacement for a `foreach` loop, and these loops are very often about *doing something* with each element of a sequence, and "doing something" usually implies some kind of side effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically you need a way of extracting lines from a `TextReader`. Here's a simple solution which will only iterate once:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(this TextReader reader)
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        yield return line;
    }
}
```

You could use that with:

```
var resultingLinesQuery = 
    new StringReader(lotsOfIncomingLinesWithNewLineCharacters)
    .ReadLines()
    .Where(s => s.Substring(0,5) == "value");
```

But ideally, you should be able to iterate over an `IEnumerable<T>` more than once. If you only need this for strings, you could use:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitIntoLines(this string text)
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader(text))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var resultingLinesQuery = 
    lotsOfIncomingLinesWithNewLineCharacters
    .SplitIntoLines()
    .Where(s => s.Substring(0,5) == "value");
```

Comment: Jon, what is the impact of use a method that does a `yield return` instead return a full collection (e.g. List<T>)?

Comment: @FelipeOriani: It will iterate lazily - so unless you call `ToList()` or something similar, you'll never have the complete collection in memory.

Comment: A flag to control transferring ownership of the reader to the enumerator would be nice.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I think I'd rather do that separately - or (ideally) change the input to a `Func<TextReader>`. For example, you can have `ReadLines(string file) { return ReadLines(() => File.OpenText()); }`. I didn't want to go into all that detail here though.